# No access to an old Apple ID due to incorrect information

Tags: apple-id

The Apple ID which is linked to my iPhone can't be accessed. I have tried 'Find my ID' but it won't accept my birthdate and emails are not being received to any of my current or old email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[Contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com), as they are are able to access and recover account details - something nobody outside of Apple can do for you.

Be prepared with any information you might have. Helpful details include (but are not limited to) current/previous addresses, credit card information, and purchase receipts that are automatically mailed to you following any (app/music/movie/etc) Store purchase.